# If $A,B$ are equinumerous, then so are their complements

Tags: elementary-set-theory

I'm interested to know if the following statement is true:

> If $A,B \subseteq X$ are equinumerous (i.e. $|A|=|B|$, or there is a bijection $A \to B$), then $X \setminus A$ and $X \setminus B$ are equinumerous as well.

This seems true even for infinite sets, but I couldn't prove it in the infinite case. I tried constructing a bijection $f:X \setminus A \to X \setminus B$ explicitly using the bijection $ A \to B$, and came up with an incomplete piecewise function

$$f(x)=\begin{cases} x & x \in X\setminus(A \cup B) \\? & x \in B \end{cases}, $$
but this doesn't seem to work. My question is, is there a nice way of proving this at all?

Thank you!

Comment: If $A,B$ infinite and $|A|\geq|B|$, then $|A\bigcup B|=|A|$.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Consider $X = \Bbb N$, $A = \Bbb N$ and $B = \Bbb N \setminus \{ 0 \}$.

Comment: Your counter-example is correct, except that zero is not a natural number.  Perhaps {1} would be a better choice.

Answer (score 3):

Unfortunately, this is not true. For a simple example, let $X=[0,1]$, $A=(0,1]$, and $B=(0,1)$.

Comment: If this *were* true, everything would be extremely boring. I don't think this is reeally unfortunate :-)